# Retrieving additional profile information from Facebook during external login/register with ASP.NET Web API 2.0 and Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

There appears to be a lot of documentation on how to get additional information from a Facebook profile using ASP.NET Identity and an MVC client, but I can't seem to find anything on how to access the additional info claims from a Web API controller.

My Startup.Auth.cs ConfigAuth method contains this, which seems to work alright if I breakpoint on JObject wholeUser = context.User

```
String XmlSchemaString = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims";
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "*",
    AppSecret = "*",
    Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            JObject wholeUser = context.User;

            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Once authenticated, wholeUser will have all the information I need like birthdate, etc. but once out of this scope, I don't know how to get to it.

I need to get this information in AccountController.RegisterExternal, but I can't seem to configure it correctly. A lot of the MVC doco around uses this in the ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

But AuthenticationManager can't be found in Web API, so if I change it to just Authentication, it returns null unless I change the parameter to be DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer. This is as close as I get, but the returned ClaimsIdentity object doesn't have any of the additional claims - just the username and ID.

So overall, it's as though I'm getting the information from Facebook properly and cramming into context.Identity, but then I have no idea how to access it from the controller. N.B: the context object in ConfigAuth is of type Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticatedContext

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need the same thing that I did, but take a look at http://aliu.ro/easy-mvc4-facebook-authentication-example/

There is a small sample project that does the Facebook Auth, retrieves the access token and makes a call using some .NET SDK that I found in NuGet

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code here;

```
            var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "*",
            AppSecret = "**",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },
        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Now in the RegisterExternal method, the claim is available to me.  I just can't figure out how to persist it in the Identity so that it can be used in other Controller calls. If i add the claim to the identity then it seems to break the User.Identity object on other calls;

```
ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
```

And the FromIdentity method;

```
            public static ExternalLoginData FromIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string userEmail = string.Empty;
            string userFacebookAccessToken = string.Empty;

            Claim providerKeyClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Claim facebookToken = identity.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("access_token"));
            Claim emailDetails = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);

            if (facebookToken != null) userFacebookAccessToken = facebookToken.Value;
            if (emailDetails != null)  userEmail = emailDetails.Value;
            //string userEmail = identity.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("emailaddress")).Value;

            if (providerKeyClaim == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Issuer)
                || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (providerKeyClaim.Issuer == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new ExternalLoginData
            {
                LoginProvider = providerKeyClaim.Issuer,
                ProviderKey = providerKeyClaim.Value,
                UserName = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name),
                Email = userEmail,
                FacebookAccessToken = userFacebookAccessToken

            };
        }
    }
```